# Loading xib from button press

Tags: macos, cocoa, xcode5, xib

I have a project that requires to load another xib file when a user press a button

In the main page of my project there are 6 buttons
each is link to another xib (NSViewController)

[image: Main Page]

When a user presses on a button it will show a nib file

[image: About EPiC Online]

Here's what I've done

```
-(IBAction)About:(id)sender {
    self.aboutViewController = [[AboutViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"AboutViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.aboutViewController.view.frame = ((NSView*)self.window.contentView).bounds;
}
```

is this correct?

Comment: Why are you asking us? Have you *tried* it? If you have and it's not working, have you set a breakpoint in your action method to see if it's even called and/or inspect self.aboutViewController to see if it loaded successfully?

Comment: self.packages = [[PackageViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PackageViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.window1.contentView addSubview:self.packages.view];
    self.packages.view.frame = ((NSView*)self.window1.contentView).bounds;
    [window1 makeKeyAndOrderFront:NSApp];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see my comment above but at a pure guess, I don't see `[self.window.contentView addSubview:self.aboutViewController.view]` being called anywhere, so if your problem is that you're not seeing the view, that's at least one sure reason why.